# How to extract coefficients for TF-IDF features?

Tags: scikit-learn, nlp

I have a dataset where I am using a text column to predict some numerical column.

**My ultimate question is this: Which words in the text column are associated with a higher/lower score?**

So my pipeline is to first vectorize my text column, and then use a ridge regression. But after I build this pipeline how do I extract the coefficents on the vectorizer feature names?

```py
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.linear_model import Ridge
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

# This is my toy data 
d = {'text': ["I am a a string", "And I am a string", "I, too am string", "And me", "Me too"], 
     'target': [3, 4, 14, 6, 7]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test= train_test_split(df['text'], df['target'], 
                                                   test_size=0.3, random_state=42)


# Here is a vectorizer 
vect = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words='english')
X_train_vect = vect.fit_transform(X_train)

# Here is a ridge regressor
model = Ridge(random_state=42)
model.fit(X_train_vect, y_train)

# Now we make a pipeline
pipe = Pipeline([('vect',vect),('model',model)])
y_pred = pipe.predict(X_test)
```

How would I go about about extracting words as coefficents from here? 
E.g: `"I am": 0.05` or whatever

Answer (score 0):

```
idf = vect.idf_
print (dict(zip(vect.get_feature_names(), idf)))
```

This should do it.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the `pipeline` in the best way. You can do the `.fit()` using the pipeline itself as follows.

```py
# Here is a vectorizer 
vect = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words='english')

# Here is a ridge regressor
model = Ridge(random_state=42)

# Now we make a pipeline
pipe = Pipeline([('vect',vect),('model',model)])
pipe.fit(X_train, y_train)
pipe.predict(X_test)

# array([8.07176068, 7.21966856])
```

Now, to know the coefficients corresponding to each feature use:

```py
# for sklearn >= 0.21.0
list(zip(pipe['vect'].get_feature_names(), pipe['model'].coef_ ))

# for sklearn < 0.21.0
list(zip(pipe.named_steps.vect.get_feature_names(), pipe.named_steps.model.coef_ ))
```